# how to send json format to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular

I wan the data to be in this format

```
{"email":"s@gmail.com","password":"1"}
```

but getting in this format

```
{ '{"email":"s@gmail.com","password":"1"}': '' }
```

my client code,

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
```

I am not sure about this,can any one suggest help please

my backend code,

```
exports.login = function( req, res ) {

console.log(req.body)
  var query = 'select * from profile where email = ? and password = ?'; 
 connection.query(query,[req.body.email,req.body.password],function(error,result,rows,fields){
    if(!!error){console.log(error)
      console.log('fail');
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  // }

  });}
```

Comment: try  `this.http.post(this.header1+'login', form, { headers: headers })`

Comment: do not append content-type, and do not use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Your `form` is already JSON. If you stringify, the result is a `string` object.

Comment: so i should remove stringify?

Comment: no use even after removing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $.ajax({
       url: this.header1+'login',
       data: {"email":"s@gmail.com","password":"1"},
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **jquery** it is pretty simple:

```
$.post('http://address', {"email":"s@gmail.com","password":"1"}).done( (response) => {
  // Request complete
}).fail((jqXHR) => {
  // Request failed 
});
```

Comment: i am using angular2

Comment: Then it's probably some problem at your backend

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

    $http({
    url: this.header1 + 'login',
    ,
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        "email": "s@gmail.com",
        "password": "1"
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

    }
}).success(function (response) {

})
```